# Android Application Keyboard Enter/Send Key

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard

While using messaging services built inside different applications, I noticed that the `Enter` key on some applications is replaced by a `send` key. As an example, the attached 5 screenshots are from Facebook Messenger, Instagram, Snapchat, Twitter and my own application.

As you can see, Snapchat and Instagram have the bottom-right key of the keyboard set as `send` with the special icon. Rest of them, including mine, do not have that. I tried to look around but could not find any documentation or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Where do I even start to achieve something like this?

*Footnote 1: I am using a Google Pixel 2 XL with Google Keyboard, but I have seen similar functionality on other devices.*

*Footnote 2: I have seen a question on overwriting the enter key's input to call a function but am looking for more traditional/sophisticated method (preferably with custom send icon).*

*Footnote 3: Order of images: My application, Snapchat, Messenger, Twitter, Instagram.*

*Footnote 4: I am not specifically looking to make an entire custom keyboard. I want to keep rest of the multimedia functions brought by Google Keyboard.*

[image: My Application][image: Snapchat][image: Messenger][image: Twitter][image: Instagram]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` on your `EditText` widget.

Answer (score 2):

try add this property on your EditText,

```
android:imeOptions="actionSend"
```

good luck!